# create balloons based on my click and animate to top of the screen ( random positions of X-axis) using Raphael.js

Tags: svg, raphael

using this code i can able to create a circle with line( like as balloon) based on my click and animate to center position of the rectangle, while animating line is not going along with circle like as balloon and how to move the of the screen ( random positions of X-axis) insted of center position.

Code:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        var canvas = Raphael(0, 0, 920, 940);
        var backboard = canvas.rect(0, 0, 920, 940).attr({ fill: 'white', stroke: 'none' });
        backboard.click(function (event, x, y) {

            var bbox = backboard.getBBox();
            var x_ratio = x / bbox.width;
            var y_ratio = y / bbox.height;
            var color = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(x_ratio * 255) + ',0,' + Math.floor(y_ratio * 255) + ")";

            // Circle
            var transient_circle = canvas.circle(x, y, 25).attr({ fill: color, stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 1 });
            transient_circle.animate({ cx: bbox.width / 2, cy: bbox.width / 3, 'fill-opacity': 0.25 }, 3000, ">",
            function () {
                transient_circle.animate({ 'stroke-opacity': 0, 'fill-opacity': 0 }, 2500, function () { transient_circle.remove(); });
            });

            // Line
            var transient_pathline = canvas.path("M" + x + " " + (y + 25) + "C" + (x - 80) + " " + (y + 200) + " " + (x + 100) + " " + (y + 400) + " " + (x - 100) + " " + (y + 120)).attr({ fill: '#fff', stroke: color, 'stroke-width': 1 });
            var _transformedPath = Raphael.transformPath('M' + (bbox.width / 2) + " " + (bbox.width / 3) + "C" + (x - 80) + " " + (y + 200) + " " + (x + 100) + " " + (y + 400) + " " + (x - 100) + " " + (y + 120), 'T300,0');
            transient_pathline.animate({ path: _transformedPath }, 1000);} }); });
```

please help me how to move the circle along with line to top of the screen like as a balloon.

Comment: Hi @Mike C. Please help me to draw a balloon and animate it.

Answer (score 0):

Code for creating balloons based on user click

```
function derivateElement(element) {

            var movAmplitude = 236

            var nx = -movAmplitude * .5 + Math.random() * movAmplitude
            var ny = -movAmplitude * .5 + Math.random() * movAmplitude

            var timing = 800 + Math.random() * 400

            element.animate({ transform: "T" + nx + ", " + ny }, timing, "easeInOut", function () { derivateElement(element) });
        }

        var canvas = Raphael(0, 0, 920, 940);
        var backboard = canvas.rect(0, 0, 920, 940).attr({ fill: 'white', stroke: 'none' });
        var index = 0;
        backboard.click(function (event, x, y) {

            var bbox = backboard.getBBox();
            var x_ratio = x / bbox.width;
            var y_ratio = y / bbox.height;
            var color = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(x_ratio * 255) + ',0,' + Math.floor(y_ratio * 255) + ")";

            // Circle
            var _circle = canvas.circle(x, y, 25).attr({ fill: color, stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 1 });
            //path
            var _pathline = canvas.path("M" + x + " " + (y + 25) + "C" + (x - 80) + " " + (y + 200) + " " + (x + 100) + " " + (y + 400) + " " + (x - 100) + " " + (y + 120)).attr({ fill: '#fff', stroke: color, 'stroke-width': 1 });

            _circle.connections = [];
            _pathline.startElement = _circle;
            _circle.connections.push(_pathline);
            _circle.connected = true;
            var CircleSet = []
            CircleSet[index] = canvas.set();
            CircleSet[index].push(_circle, _pathline);
            derivateElement(CircleSet[index]);
            index++;
        });
```